# sudoku check subgrid error

Tags: java, sudoku

Hi can anyone tell me what im doing wrong here?
i want to check each subgrid for repeated values in a 9by 9 square.

my method works first by creating each subgrid a one dimensional array which can then check each row for each subgrid. and for it to go to each subgrid i provide its coordinates myself.
 it checks the first grid 0,0 but does not check other subgrids for repeated values.

can anyone tell me what im doing wrong?

```
public class SudokuPlayer
{
private int [][]  game;
public enum CellState { EMPTY, FIXED, PLAYED };
private CellState[][] gamestate;
private int [][] copy;

private static final int GRID_SIZE=9;

private boolean whichGameToReset;
private int len;
private int stateSize;
private int row;
private int col;

private boolean coordinates(int startX, int startY)
{


           row=startX;
           col=startY;
          if(isBoxValid()==false)
          {
              return false; 
          }

           return true;
    }



public boolean check()
{
    if(coordinates(0,0)==false)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(coordinates(0,3)==false)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(coordinates(0,6)==false)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(coordinates(1,0)==false)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if( coordinates(1,3)==false)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if( coordinates(1,6)==false)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(coordinates(2,0)==false)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(coordinates(2,3)==false)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(coordinates(2,6)==false)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}




private boolean isBoxValid()
{

    int[] arrayCopy = new int[game.length];


    int currentRow = (row/3)*3;
    int currentCol = (col/3)*3;
    int i = 0;

    for ( int r =currentRow; r < 3; r++)
    {

        for( int c =currentCol; c < 3; c++)
        {
            arrayCopy[i] = game[r][c];
            i++;
        }
    }

    for ( int p =0; p < arrayCopy.length; p++)
    {
        for ( int j = p+1; j < arrayCopy.length; j++)
        {
            if ( arrayCopy[p] == arrayCopy[j] && arrayCopy[j]!=0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: "int currentRow = (row/3)*3"  --- huh what?

Comment: You're going to have to tell us more than "it doesn't do what it's supposed to do."  What are you seeing?  What's the output, and what makes you think only the first subgrid is being checked?  Also, don't paste the whole thing, just the relevant bits.

Comment: say the first sub grid starts at row=0 and col=0 and ends at row=2,col=2. if their is a repeated value it would return false meaning the grid is not valid. the code for this is working fine.

Comment: but if their is a repeated value in another subgrid it will return true. which is wrong. its supposed to return false.

Comment: i want it to check every box for repeated values within 9 by 9 grid

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your isBoxValid() method.  You are initializing `r` and `c` to be `currentRow` and `currentCol`, respectively, but you run the loop up to a hard coded value of 3, not `3+currentRow` or `3+currentCol`.  When currentRow and currentCol are 0, it works fine, but for other numbers, not so much.

Oh, another thing that's nice about writing concise code: it's easier to see where your errors are.  Take another look at the numbers you've hard-coded into `check()`: you're incrementing the columns by 3 and the rows by 1.  That would be much easier to spot if you compressed it into a pair of `for` loops.

Comment: Not related directly to your question, but your code can be made a lot prettier with minimal effort.  For example, your `check()` method can be implemented with 5 lines: `for(int i=0;i<9;i+=3) for(int j=0;j<9;j+=3) if(!coordinates(i,j) return false; return true;`

Comment: if i change the 3 to currentRow+3 and currentCol+3 respectively it does check the sub grid at row = 0 and col=3,6

Comment: but not when the row is different eg row=6 and col=0:s